# Please how can I edit this code to show Page Row Selector for table with up to 200,000 records

Tags: php, mysql, datatable

Good afternoon.

Please I need your kind assistance. I have been working on a PHP MySQL web project and everything is going well. However, I have a datatable that seem to be malfunctioning.

The code below is that of a datatable gotten from this site https://www.webslesson.info/2016/10/datatables-jquery-plugin-with-php-mysql-and-bootstrap.html.

The datatable runs well and shows the search box, page navigation and page row selector (10, 25, 50, 100) correctly for tables with less than a 100 records but each time I connect it to a table that has more than 200,000 records, the table malfunctions. That is it hides the search box, page navigation and page row selector and then loads records endlessly.

**My question now is how I can make the page row selector (10, 25, 50, 100) to work properly such that irrespective of the number of records in the table, the page will load the default 10 records, show the search box and the page navigation buttons at the bottom of the table**.

Thank you

```js
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#employee_data').DataTable();  
 });  
 </script>
```

```html
 <?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "blog_samples");  
 $query ="SELECT * FROM tbl_employee ORDER BY ID DESC";  
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Webslesson Tutorial | Datatables Jquery Plugin with Php MySql and Bootstrap</title>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>  
           <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>            
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container">  
                <h3 align="center">Datatables Jquery Plugin with Php MySql and Bootstrap</h3>  
                <br />  
                <div class="table-responsive">  
                     <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered">  
                          <thead>  
                               <tr>  
               <td>ID</td> 
                                    <td>Name</td>  
                                    <td>Address</td>  
                                    <td>Gender</td>  
                                    <td>Designation</td>  
                                    <td>Age</td>  
         <td data-sortable="false">Action</td>           
                               </tr>  
                          </thead>  
                          <?php  
                          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                          {  
                               echo '  
                               <tr>                                      
         <td>'.$row["tin_id"].'</td>           
         <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>  
                                    <td>'.$row["address"].'</td>  
                                    <td>'.$row["gender"].'</td>  
                                    <td>'.$row["designation"].'</td>  
                                    <td>'.$row["age"].'</td>  
         <td>button</td>             
                               </tr>  
                               ';  
                          }  
                          ?>  
                     </table>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>
```

---

It's been a wonderful learning time.

Meanwhile, I am so sorry for not returning since to post the answer to this question.

I was able to resolve it by creating a custom server side. The code is too long for me to paste here. However, for those with issues, kindly visit this link https://www.webslesson.info/2017/01/php-pdo-ajax-crud-with-data-tables-and-bootstrap-modals.html. Copy the codes into a PHP editor, rewrite the codes to suits your case and you are good to go.

The code lines are easy to understand!

Enjoy!

Comment: It is way too many records. Think about it: You are trying to insert +200.000 row nodes to the DOM!  You must take a look at https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side try google something called `ssp.class.php` ...

Comment: What happened to the responses I posted here,,,,

@davidkonrad: Anyway I tried your suggestion and it helped reduce the loading time. But now how can I make the Page row selector, search box and navigator to show???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add page row selector for values such as 100, 250, 500, 1000 to my datatable, I add the following line of codes:

```
     **"aLengthMenu": [[10, 50, 100, 250, 500, 1000], [100, 250, 500, 1000]],
     "iDisplayLength": 10**
```

to my script. The **"iDisplayLength": 100** will be default value

```
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#employee_data').DataTable();
     **"aLengthMenu": [[10, 50, 100, 250, 500, 1000], [10, 50, 100, 250, 500, 1000]],
     "iDisplayLength": 10**
 });  
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

After all efforts to add the server side with the buttons as I wanted, I couldn't so I resorted to using this PHP-CODEIGNITER-DATATABLE-SERVERSIDE-CRUD-AJAX as seen in the link 
https://github.com/ahmadsolehin/PHP-CODEIGNITER-DATATABLE-SERVERSIDE-CRUD-AJAX.

Please note that adding the server side ajax code in my earlier table want to main problem. The main issue was adding the button alongside. I couldn't do that, hence the need for a change.

You can download it, make a few adjustments and get it running. Its running my 300,000 records quite well and I am OK with that.